# Filter out nestled values in object and arrays and return full object type

Tags: typescript

I have data that looks likem that is of type IconItems:

```
{
  title: "Category title",
  description: "Example description",
  lists: [
    {
      id: "popular",
      title: "Popular",
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "title",
          provider: "provider",
          image: ""
        },
      ....
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "new",
      title: "New",
      items: [
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "studioss2",
          provider: "provider",
          image: ""
        },
       ....
      ]
    }
```

I want to filter the nestled items (type IconItem, in singular) array based on a string value.

For this I have defined these two values:

```
const filterKeyOpt: Array<keyof IconItem> = ["title", "provider", "image"];
const searchQuery = 'sTudioSS'
```

I try to filter out the data

```
const logData = () => {
     let filteredData = data?.lists.map((item) => item.items.filter((i) => {
      return filterKeyOpt.some((key) => i[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
    } /// returns  IconItem[][] | undefined but I want to return type IIconItems | undefined
    ))
console.log(filteredData)
}
```

But the output is of type

```
IconItem[][]
```

But I want the full thing/type. Ie. filter out on a nestled value and give back a copy of the data object, with matching properties. How to do that?

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=69&ssc=32&pln=69&pc=20#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXASTaMaoFMC2EMAvDAN4BQMMUAllADa4owBEAwkrgOYgBOATxr0mrADRV4uCMD60ADnXAtWAUQAeCfPKZSZcxbXDjJDWtAgsA2pOqVqDmLTgr5IeQFcGCPicfU6RmY2AAV3Lx8-f3oCSxgbfwd7RIdnFgBGCRSHQKYVXNwo7Pk%20EAA3Z1w%20V1KKuCqilNp8BG5g1lZbfwBfLJTk7LSYACY%207IL8kVxhxsSS8srqtmgPOCMIDdnolraVTuzuruoAXS7eroHUlzYwXAB3LYm2ADl7rZjCayOk78chgBYxiknqwCv8to55nUqjUFvVfEDEs1Wu19ilztlLkjrqNfjkppMggBWCEOKGLFQIvHUZG7NhoxKHRKnRxMmCnboAbgoFFoYDwfAAZghgLgYBgsDhYuRJE9oHIwNxudR6voFEowCx5XylaZzFA4hLwFL8FZjtzDrz%20VVhaLxZhjXh8DKaddtYrlcIglqoArdTSnYbJU6zRaeXyBbaxQ7sE6XU5rmAPPgAEZVT1y306z3k%20E%20v2e2nBd26y1YaAwQW0BgCgDSuAEAHlFCwAIJ8PgIAQAHgA1g2QILxcGCAA%20EjxUFTcRsXMNMRsIusc0UcuwCC4HzAAAWAEUPFUhKQAOQQAAqqyMAGUr8eeWuYAwQNwACJIBATgAUAEoSOOsUwsBVjWVS4HAb7IBOiDIAA-AAdGYFhwS08ifp%20Hy-sQ44fHBHwQHBwECmhtCYf%203x8LgUAeHwYCVtWdYNs2UBwRAID4LgaH9gIpFOFYXHHHBUAgFeWaKj%20gkgAAMiAdxVJwG7iXywAMKs0ifhuW57geggSdJsl8PJHHfsZZwwAA9BZMAUVRNFEMOjoEGaZowAAPjAHhgPUVa3HAMAph4sBoDAdwIPyNAgFZlHUbRUACPI0YxiaRBuR5Xl8mBXQmeWIBMAhz6foRoHge%2034UJaT6vu%20P7ckAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=84&ssc=2&pln=66&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDAku0Z1QKYC2EMAvDAN4BQMMUAllADZ5oBEAwkngOYgBOAT1oNmrADTV4eCMD50ADvXBsAogA8EBecyky5iuuHGTGdaBDQBtSTSo17MOnDbyQ8gK6MEfYw5r0mFhhWAAU3T29fPwZCCxhrP3s7RPsnNABGCRT7AOY2XLwo7Pk%20EAA3Jzw%20F1KKuCqilLoCBG4g1lYbPwBfLJTk7LSYACY%207IL8kTxhxsSS8srq4Oh3OEMIDdnolra2TuzurpoAXS7eroHU52CwPAB3LYnggDl7rZiiKyOk74chgBYxiknqwCv8tg55nUqjUFvUfEDEs1Wu19ilztlLkjrqNfjkppNAgBWCH2KGLNgIvE0ZG7YJoxKHRKnBxMmCnboAbkolDoYHwfAAZghgHgMFhwLhYhRJE9oHIwNxuTR6noFEowGh5XylSYzFA4phsFKCJZjtzDrz%20VVhaLxcb8AQZTTrtrFcrhIEtVAFbqaY7DQ7CGaLTy%20QLbWKJThHc7HNcwO4CAAjKoeuU%20nUe8nw72%20j20oJu3WW7DQGCCuiMAUAaTwAgA8oo0ABBPh8BACAA8AGt6yBBRggwQAHykeKgqbiYI5hpiYKF1jmyhl2AQPDeYAACwAiu4qkIyAByCAAFVWhgAypejzzVzBGCBuAARJAIccACgAlKQx8lmLAqC0AI8h4AO8BvuOlwAHSwYgyBAqY5hoPBCDQUhBrQS08gfhhv5xg4AD0hHZKRMAAHoAPzfHweBQO4fBgBQMDETA4CMEILRQNuOqOAGeKweh%20qIqkAZoBh0EfBA0GVtWVQfh8%20FYn4rFkWRVHUhWVa1vWTZQNBEAgAQeAfh%20fYCD%20JBjh8ljmcc0FQCAl6Zoq34OSAAAyIB3FUnDrm5fLAIwqzSB%2066bru%206CO5Xk%20XwfkmV%20SV4t0X7fGyNCpTJ2nyXhVkEfYrHsUIYDgAAtIQihCBhEA0XRDFMRJUnoXgipQFuZxpZlki0fRjEwGhNUtW1W4wJRA0wGg7hgPUla3HAoaUI%20L5vt%203JAA)

```
const logData = () => {
  let a: typeof data = {
    ...data,
    lists: data.lists.map(list => {
      //                  ^?
      return { // only matching items
        ...list,
        items: list.items.filter(item => {
          //                     ^?
          filterKeyOpt.some((key) => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
        })
      }
    }).filter(list => {
      // only non-empty lists
      return list.items.length
    })
  }
  return a.lists.length ? a : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Looks more promising, however, lists return undefined even though the query should match a value:  {
  "title": "Category title",
  "description": "Example description",
  "lists": []
}

Comment: Saw the issue, a return was missing in the filtering between the items and searchquery. With that, code works fine. Thank you!